# Why do I print my barcode does not match the output result with the size of the paper label when printing in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, barcode, picturebox, barcode-printing

I am using Zen Barcode Rendering Framework to create bar codes in VB.NET windows form application.

From the Winform application I want to print directly to the barcode printer via graphic without using the language of the printer. Is there something wrong with the code please guide me.

Thanks

```
   Private Sub BtnScreen_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BtnScreen.Click
        ' if there was a previous image in the picture box, dispose of it now
        If PicCode.Image IsNot Nothing Then
            PicCode.Image.Dispose()
        End If

        ' create a 24 bit image that is the size of your picture box
        Dim img = New Bitmap(PicCode.Width, PicCode.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
        ' wrap it in a graphics object
        Using g = Graphics.FromImage(img)
            ' send that graphics object to the rendering code
            RenderBarcodeInfoToGraphics(g, TxtCode.Text, TxtInfo.Text, New Rectangle(0, 0, PicCode.Width, PicCode.Height))
        End Using

        ' set the new image in the picture box
        PicCode.Image = img
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnPrinter_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles BtnPrinter.Click
        ' create a document that will call the same rendering code but
        ' this time pass the graphics object the system created for that device
        Dim doc = New PrintDocument()
        AddHandler doc.PrintPage, Sub(s, printArgs)
                                      ' send that graphics object to the rendering code using the size
                                      ' of the media defined in the print arguments
                                      RenderBarcodeInfoToGraphics(printArgs.Graphics, TxtCode.Text, TxtInfo.Text, printArgs.PageBounds)
                                  End Sub

        ' save yourself some paper and render to a print-preview first
        Using printPrvDlg = New PrintPreviewDialog With {.Document = doc}
            printPrvDlg.ShowDialog()
        End Using

        ' finally show the print dialog so the user can select a printer
        ' and a paper size (along with other miscellaneous settings)
        Using pd = New PrintDialog With {.Document = doc}
            If pd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
                doc.Print()
            End If
        End Using
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' This method will draw the contents of the barcode parameters to any
    ''' graphics object you pass in.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="g">The graphics object to render to</param>
    ''' <param name="code">The barcode value</param>
    ''' <param name="info">The information to place under the bar code</param>
    ''' <param name="rect">The rectangle in which the design is bound to</param>
    Private Shared Sub RenderBarcodeInfoToGraphics(ByVal g As Graphics, ByVal code As String, ByVal info As String, ByVal rect As Rectangle)
        ' Constants to make numbers a little less magical
        Const barcodeHeight As Integer = 50
        Const marginTop As Integer = 20
        Const codeFontFamilyName As String = "Courier New"
        Const codeFontEmSize As Integer = 10
        Const marginCodeFromCode As Integer = 10
        Const infoFontFamilyName As String = "Arial"
        Const infoFontEmSize As Integer = 12
        Const marginInfoFromCode As Integer = 10

        ' white background
        g.Clear(Color.White)

        ' We want to make sure that when it draws, the renderer doesn't compensate
        ' for images scaling larger by blurring the image. This will leave your
        ' bars crisp and clean no matter how high the DPI is
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor

        ' generate barcode
        Using img = BarcodeDrawFactory.Code128WithChecksum.Draw(code, barcodeHeight)
            ' daw the barcode image
            g.DrawImage(img, New Point(rect.X + (rect.Width \ 2 - img.Width \ 2), rect.Y + marginTop))
        End Using

        ' now draw the code under the bar code
        Using br = New SolidBrush(Color.Black)
            ' calculate starting position of text from the top
            Dim yPos = rect.Y + marginTop + barcodeHeight + marginCodeFromCode

            ' align text to top center of area
            Dim sf = New StringFormat With {
            .Alignment = StringAlignment.Center,
            .LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Near
        }

            ' draw the code, saving the height of the code text
            Dim codeTextHeight = 0
            Using font As New Font(codeFontFamilyName, codeFontEmSize, FontStyle.Regular)
                codeTextHeight = CInt(Math.Truncate(Math.Round(g.MeasureString(code, font).Height)))

                g.DrawString(code, font, br, New Rectangle(rect.X, yPos, rect.Width, 0), sf)
            End Using

            ' draw the info below the code
            Using font As New Font(infoFontFamilyName, infoFontEmSize, FontStyle.Regular)
                g.DrawString(info, font, br, New Rectangle(rect.X, yPos + codeTextHeight + marginInfoFromCode, rect.Width, 0), sf)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
```

RESULT IN FORM

[image: RESULT IN FORM]

RESULT IN PRINT PREVIEW

[image: RESULT IN PRINT PREVIEW]

RESULT OUTPUT IN LABEL

[image: RESULT OUTPUT IN LABEL]

Label Dimensions

[image: Label Dimensions]

Comment: Complete guess here, might not even be a code problem, but wondering about the label vs printer config.  You've got one saying the label is 33mm and one saying 3.937 inches (or approx 100mm).  Would think they both can't be right.

Comment: @Hursey, The printer configuration has nothing to do with the label size so it will follow the size specified from the coding

Comment: In my experience and admit not all printer drives are equal, having the printer config right sure does matter.  Especially if you're telling it to print a label that is 33mm wide on  media the print driver thinks is 100mm wide.  Commonly in label printer drivers/utilities there is a calibration tool that will automatically sense the labels and do the config for you